# Twitter bootstrap margin ul tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I am using Twitter Bootstrap, but can't understand
How to set `margin 0 0 9 15` for

```
[ul class="taxons-list"]
```

On the my site [vk-magazin.com](http://vk-magazin.com)
Following result I want to achive:

[image: margin]

Comment: Actual styles? Maybe: `margin: 0 0 9px 15px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS rule:

```
ul.taxons-list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 9px 15px;
}
```

I edited your HTML using Firebug and this style and it works just as your picture intends.